# Content Editable Div Copy&Paste Limit

Tags: html, keypress, jscript

i have a message box with an Edit option, when the user edits the message i have a limit set to 300characters for keypress ,But When i copy&Paste the limit is exceeded with no effect from my Jscript limit code.

Can anybody see where i am going wrong with the code below. Please And Thank you.

```
var ebm=document.getElementById('editSeller'+varmessageid+'');


                        var messbox=$(ebm).text();
                        var messlength = messbox.length;
                        var amount=300;
                        var leftlength=amount-messlength;



                                //delete & backspace keys
                            document.addEventListener('keyup', function(event) {
                                const key = event.key;
                                if (key === "Backspace" || key === "Delete") {

                                 var messbox=$(ebm).text();
                                var messlength = messbox.length;
                                var amount=300;
                                var leftlength=amount-messlength;


                                    if (leftlength <1 ) {leftlength=0
                                    $(ebm).css('border', '1px dashed red');
                                    event.preventDefault();
                                    }
                                        else {
                                        $(ebm).css('border', '1px dashed #07f310');
                                        }



                                $('#CSeller'+varmessageid+'').text('Characters Left: '+leftlength);
                                 }
                            });


 //ascii keys
                             $(ebm).on('keypress', function(e){



                                var messbox=$(ebm).text();
                                var messlength = messbox.length;
                                var amount=299;
                                var leftlength=amount-messlength;


                                    if (leftlength <1 ) {leftlength=0
                                    $(ebm).css('border', '1px dashed red');
                                    e.preventDefault();
                                    }
                                        else  {
                                        $(ebm).css('border', '1px dashed #07f310');
                                        }



                                $('#CSeller'+varmessageid+'').text('Characters Left: '+leftlength);



                            });
```

Comment: This is the Copy&paste problem, I Solved the  Limiting Number of Characters in a ContentEditable div

Comment: You can trigger ctrl+v event and get the realtime characters length inside that div and trim content after 300 characters using substring.

Comment: yes, iv been reading up on this.  Going to give it a try, allthough it will require another function ..Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Added another function as below using .onpaste 
seems to work so far sop good...

yet to check browser compatibility.

```
var ebm=document.getElementById('editSeller'+varmessageid+'');

   ebm.onpaste = function(event){
     var messbox=$(ebm).text();
     var messlength = messbox.length;
     var amount=300;
     var leftlength=amount-messlength;


    if (leftlength <1 ) {leftlength=0
     $(ebm).css('border', '1px dashed red');
      event.preventDefault();
       }

       else {
           $(ebm).css('border', '1px dashed #07f310');
          }

        $('#CSeller'+varmessageid+'').text('Characters Left: '+leftlength);
};
```